# Change docker directory permissions after shared folder is mounted

Tags: php, docker-compose

I have a PHP project which requires me to change the owner of the /storage folder:

This is my docker-compose.yml

```
version: '2'
services:
web:
    build:
        context: ./
        dockerfile: ./docker/web.docker
    volumes:
        - ./:/var/www
    ports:
        - "8080:80"
    links:
        - app


app:
    build:
        context: ./
        dockerfile: ./docker/app.docker
    volumes:
        - ./:/var/www
    links:
        - database
    environment:
        - "DB_PORT=3306"
        - "DB_HOST=database"
        - "REDIS_PORT=6379"
        - "REDIS_HOST=cache"
```

app.docker

```
FROM php:7.1-fpm

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y libmcrypt-dev mysql-client \
&& docker-php-ext-install mcrypt pdo_mysql bcmath

WORKDIR /var/www

RUN chown www-data:www-data -R /var/www/storage/
```

The thing is that when chown www-data:www-data is run, I guess the folder is still not mounted and therefore I get the following error:

```
chown: cannot access '/var/www/storage/': No such file or directory
```

How can I posibly solve this? Is there a hook to run commands after the shared folder has been mounted?

Comment: Could be your php.ini setting for [open base dir](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.open-basedir)?

Comment: I don't understand how this relates to my issue. Maybe I'm wrong but I think the only problem is that the chown command is run before my volume is mounted.

Comment: You are mounting the volume like this `./:/var/www`, so perhaps your command should refer to the path `./storage` rather than `/var/www/storage`? you can always confirm by connecting to the docker instance and listing dir contents with `cd / && /df -h` see what is mounted where?

Comment: I'll give that a try, thanks